# jquery tabs in ajax mode help for safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, safari

I've created jQuery tabs in ajax mode.

In one of my tabs I have an application back button that uses `javascript: history.go(-1)`.

Everything works fine in IE. When I click my back button it takes me to the initial page in the iFrame.  But when I try the same functionality in Safari the button takes me to my home page. I also realized Safari's browser buttons do the same thing while IE's browser buttons work perfectly.

I cannot understand the reason why my page doing this. Any ideas to fix it?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                    $( anchor.hash ).html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Fetch external content via Ajax for the tabs by setting an href value in the tab links.  While the Ajax request is waiting for a response, the tab label changes to say "Loading...", then returns to the normal label once loaded.</p>
<p>Tabs 3 and 4 demonstrate slow-loading and broken AJAX tabs, and how to handle serverside errors in those cases. Note: These two require a webserver to interpret PHP. They won't work from the filesystem.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `javascript: self.history.go(-1)`

the problem occurs because Safari tries to call window.history.go(-1) leading to your problem

Further reading: http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/webkit-bug-hash-history-iframe/

Comment: Well, when I click my back button now, for my first click it seems unresponsive and then i click again it takes me to my home page.

Comment: The other thing I realized is when i open my application using safari my back button works. But the tabbed interface seems the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: what about opening you application in an iframe, to check if the problem is iframe or tabs?
If the problem is an iframe, try my solution again